# Rails scope with jsonb column: query for no value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord

I'm trying to add a scope to my model.

I have an attribute

```
t.jsonb    "webexes",                     default: {},   null: false
```

I need to count the item where webexes is not empty.

I try with

```
UserActivity.where.not(webexes: '')
```

But of course I have an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you set files as

```
t.jsonb    "webexes",                     default: {},   null: false
```

it looks like: `webex jsobnb NOT NULL DEFAULT '{}'` in postgres. And your query must looks:

```
UserActivity.where.not(webexes: '{}')
```